No sound in Debian 12 on laptop except if specifying hw manually, pipewire problem?
Following my previous question with same title I have installed the 1.2.12 version of ALSA drivers and did get expected behaviour with pavucontrol... for one session.
Now I can't produce sound except when testing with speaker-test -Dhw:1,0 -c2 -r48000 -f S16_LE or in the same way with Audacity.
pavucontrol doesn't see anymore my sound card, and reports only Dummy output as being available.
pipewire is running:
$ps -elf | grep pipe
0 S me     1672    1641  0  80   0 - 17418 do_epo Jul04 ?        00:05:11 /usr/bin/pipewire
0 S me     1675    1641  0  80   0 - 14065 do_epo Jul04 ?        00:06:27 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

but pactl sees only the dummy output:
$pactl list sinks
Sink #723
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: auto_null
    Description: Dummy Output
    Driver: PipeWire

Alsa sees the card:
$alsaucm listcards
  0: hw:1
    HP-HPElitex360104014inchG102_in_1NotebookPC-SBKPF-8B41

What am I missing/doing wrong...??
EDIT
Inspired by brute force pulseaudio solution, pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start, I just found even more bestial killall pipewire && pipewire & has temporarily solved the issue. pactl list sinks was giving:
Sink #51
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink
    Description: Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS Speaker + Headphones
    Driver: PipeWire

However, on the same session later, there is no sink at all anymore showing.
